# Testing decorated constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, jestjs

I am trying to test a class which uses [inversify](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) for dependency injection and using `@inject()` to decorate parameters.

```
@injectable()
export class SaveManager {
    constructor(
        @inject(INJECTABLE.STORAGE) storage: IStorage, //Uncovered Line: 15
        @inject(Configuration) configuration: Configuration //Uncovered Line: 16
    ) {
        this.storage = storage;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

But the branch coverage of this class shows me that:

```
    @inject(INJECTABLE.STORAGE) storage: IStorage, //Uncovered Line: 15
    @inject(Configuration) configuration: Configuration //Uncovered Line: 16
```

These lines are not covered.

```
File                     |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line  
SaveManager.ts           |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |      100 |          15,16
```

What should I test here to achieve 100% coverage and how can I test a constructor parameter decorator?

I know that I can use `container.get()` but I should be able to test decorators too.

Comment: Seems like there is an open issue with test case coverage tool: 
https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/issues/70, unless you are using a different tool.

Comment: @DipenShah according to that open issue - it depends on the version but I upgraded mocha - chai and everything - still experiencing % Branch non-cover. I even tried injecting null/undefined combo and it won't drop

Answer (score 1):

With *current versions* of package dependencies code coverage *works fine*.
You can use any of tests bellow and you will get 100% coverage of your `SaveManager`.

*Resolve instance using InversifyJS:*

```js
test('Resolve SaveManager', () => {
    const manager = myContainer.get(SaveManager);
    expect(manager).not.toBe(null);
});
```

*Create instance directly:*

```js
test('Create new SaveManager', () => {
    const storage = myContainer.get<IStorage>(INJECTABLE.STORAGE);
    const config = myContainer.get<Configuration>(Configuration);

    const manager = new SaveManager(storage, config);
    expect(manager).not.toBe(null);
});
```

*Result coverage is in both cases:*

```
 PASS  tests/save-manager.test.ts
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                 |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
...
 save-manager.ts     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Package versions used:

- typescript 3.5.3
- inversify 5.0.1
- jest 24.9.0
- reflect-metadata 0.1.13